# OWIN and HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, owin

It seems that OWIN is not relying anymore on old ASP.NET plumbing, so Session based values can't be set anymore

Still, I didn't find a simple way to uniquely identify anomymous users per browser session in OWIN itself (like SessionId was helping me to do).

Any ideas? :)

Comment: You could add your own OWIN middleware that sets a persistent cookie that you could read on subsequent requests. That's what the `SessionStateModule` is doing under the hood anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I jumped to conclusions.

I just forgot that in order to have a Session for a given browser, you just need to set at least one value in the user Session :)

Cheers, Ben

Comment: Please close/delete the question if there isn't a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that OWIN is not relying anymore on old ASP.NET plumbing, so Session based values can't be set anymore

First, OWIN and Session have absolutely nothing to do with each other.  They are completely independent namespaces/features.

If you're web.config is not properly [configured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  session won't work.  You could turn off OWIN and session would still work.  You could turn off sessions and OWIN would still work.

> Still, I didn't find a simple way to uniquely identify anomymous users per browser session in OWIN itself (like SessionId was helping me to do).

This never changed (since you haven't given any context I'll assume within a controller):

```
if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  // user is not anonymous...
}
```